# How to cross-platform remote procedure call in C++ (Linux/Win)

Tags: c++, linux, windows, cross-platform, rpc

I want one application on a linux host to call procedures from applications on Win7x64 in a VM. I guess that the VM runs on the linux host does not matter since it should use sockets. How do approach this plan? Are there any libraries for that in the internet?

**Edit:**

Well I took am look at all of them. XMLRPC seems to be some kind of predecessor of SOAP. Prototbuf seem to me like having the focus on easy serialization of large objects. So my decision falls on SOAP. But now I am searching for a nice-to-use c++ binding. I read a few pages of the apache axis2 manual but its everything else but nice-to-use, and anyway in C.

Another question in my specific case is: Isn't it easier to send just send some textual numbers plus parameters to identify the procedures to call and reply in textual form, as I know the signature of the called procedures?

**Edit2:**
As SOAP is just a standard and RPC is just curious, (Imagined something like function pointers over IP :D) ,imho none of them all is a solution. But ZeroMQ is indeed a progress.

Comment: Augmented my answer DIY alternative. But, in your case, where you can choose, I'd look at the libraries with a license that works for you, then I'd pick the most simple to use, with best example code for your case, but alao most mature/stable, and smallest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no magic to RPC. I would suggest having a look at a combination of ZeroMQ and [Google protobuf](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/). ZeroMQ is a very easy to use messaging system (your communication layer). You would use the [REQ/REP pattern](http://zguide2.zeromq.org/cpp%3ahwclient). Google protobuf is used to describe and serialize/deserialize your messages. Both libraries are cross-platform and even cross language (ruby, python, c++, etc. etc.)

Comment: 0MQ is great, protobuff is hard to understand. But i will go through it. But I am facing problems in desinging my software system. Would be kind if you have a look at. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13258030/asynchronuous-task-which-architecture-or-pattern-in-zeromq

Answer (score 1):

Have you taken a look at [SOAP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOAP)? It has pros and cons but may meet your needs.

The fact that your Windows box is VM shouldn't make a difference providing that it's up and running, and so long as the system you choose treats the servers as logically separate sockets normally would, your solution will remain flexible.

Answer (score 1):

One decent alternative is XMLRPC, which runs on top of HTTP. It's simpler than SOAP, at least. I've used it for Java-Python communication, and it was not much code then, but don't know any C++ libraries to recommend, so I'll just say http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML-RPC and its C++ section to that.

Edit after edited question: For a really simple solution, just use plain HTTP, mapping request path to function and giving parameters with GET or POST. Return value in HTTP response data as simply as you can: plain text for number or string, for more complex return value a binary blob if binary compatibility can be ensured (same CPU, same word size, plain struct, using compiler struct packing options if needed), or as json (or even XML, but then you are starting to reinvent SOAP/XMLRPC...).