# Asynchronous tasks. Which architecture? (Or pattern in zeroMQ)

Tags: c++, networking, network-programming, client-server, zeromq

I want one application on a Linux(Server) host to communicate with applications on Win7(Client) in a VM. Lib of choice is ZeroMQ. But how do I manage asynchronous tasks?

Let me give an example:
The application in the VM generates tasks in arbitrary intervals and sends them to the Linux box. This will process them but needs some time to answer. In this time the socket in REQ/REP pattern is blocked and incoming tasks from the WinApp can not be forwarded to the LinuxApp. How should I solve this? How is this generally solved, even without 0MQ. Do I have to make both to servers and clients and establish two connections?

Requirements:

- A client is a unique task generator.
- Server creates a workerthread for each connecting client.
- Server establishes a unique connection between client an workerthread.(Some tunnle)
- -> (REQ/REQ between each client-workerthread pair over one socket)
- Server must forward incoming tasks instantly.
- Server must be able to handle multiple clients (and therefore connections to WTs).

Hence its not possible to achieve the REQ/REP/REQ/REP/... sequence.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at the several patterns described in the [ZMQ Guide](http://zguide.zeromq.org/page%3aall) and see if one of them fits better than simple `REQ/REP`.

In general your server on the linux box seems to need implementation of `ROUTER/DEALER` pattern that will forward incoming tasks to a set of workers.

ZMQ has it's own topology compared to traditional socket based client/server solutions. Other solutions might be to implement a socket based server that uses a thread pool to forward the incoming tasks.

**UPDATE:**
Since you've been precising on your requirements I think the majordomo pattern might be a good and reliable starting point for your purposes. There might be better fitting patterns as @gvd mentions in his comments.

Comment: See the following link http://zguide.zeromq.org/page:all#Least-Recently-Used-Routing-LRU-Pattern

Comment: @gvd LRU really?!? My first thought was rather s.th. like [majordomo](http://zguide.zeromq.org/page:all#Service-Oriented-Reliable-Queuing-Majordomo-Pattern), but well could be overkill depending on the client requirements (multiple at the same time a.s.o.).

Comment: That would work too. You can also combine several patterns like Mongrel2 does (push/pull and pub/sub)

Comment: @gvd Yes, ZMQ has a very fine grained pattern catalog that provides lots of possible solutions. Sometimes that makes it pretty hard to choose one from these. IMHO LRU is just an escape point if nothing else really fits.

Comment: Sorry but its hard for me to understand what LRU and SOR make such suitable for this situation. Maybe due to my non-native english. But i stumbled upon [Asynchronous Client-Server](http://zguide.zeromq.org/page:all#Asynchronous-Client-Server). That sounds quite appropriate.

Comment: @DevNoob Yes, keep with that! I mentioned it in my answer first. There are subtle differences for more elaborate patterns, as I mentioned it's not so easy to get the points of them at a first shot reading the guide (read it twice, think over, read again as suggested). Start out experimenting on the behaviors, that will give you the best clue of what's working for your situation and what not. Note that you might want to use inproc sockets for your server implementation.

Comment: @DevNoob BTW, if you have a look at the detail in fig. 44 it looks exactly the same as described in the majordomo pattern.

Answer (score 3):

As DevNoob says, the asynchronous client server pattern sounds like the one you need.

"LRU" means least-recently used, but I've removed that term from the latest text of the Guide, and am using "load-balancing" instead. Since the goal is to load-balance across a set of workers...

Answer (score 2):

I know you mentioned ZMQ as your lib of choice, but may I humbly suggest Akka (www.akka.io)?  Akka has a ZQM extension which we've had good experiences with, so you can readily translate between its transport mechanism (netty-based) and ZMQ.  It implements the Actor Model and, more importantly, provides an 'ask' and a 'tell' for async processing across worker actors.  Akka also seems to compete quite favorably with the likes of ZMQ in terms of speed of messaging and is documented far better in my experience.

One thing Akka does not have is cross-language support, but we're using the ZMQ extension to achieve this now.  The combination of ZMQ and Akka has proven to be a very powerful and flexible platform indeed.